# Search a text file for data and echo

Tags: php, file, search, text

I'm trying to use php to open a text file to search for data in the file like: (xxx,xxx)

If text exists for it to echo something like: "found (xxx,xxx) in text file" if the text does not match any data in the text file then to echo "no match found".

I can more or less get by in php but this I've no idea how to even start.

Comment: What have you tried until now? I guess google-ing on how to open & read files in PHP will get you started.

Comment: What kind of file is it? Can you give us an example of its contents? What have you tried thus far? Was there any code that didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very simple tutorial at tizag
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php

and you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php to search for a string to see if it exists or not